# How to execute webpack --watch and another script?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I want to compile my es6 code with babel using webpack and then run another script that starts a server in dev mode.

How can I achieve this?
When running the script `webpack --watch && node build/index.js` only the first part of the script is executed

Answer (score 4):

Only the first part is executed because Webpack in watch mode (`webpack --watch`) will continue running, and the shell will wait for it to return, because the return value is required for the `&&` (AND) operator.

You should run them in parallel. You can use for example [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) package (`npm install --save-dev concurrently`). And your script would look like this:

```
concurrently "webpack --watch" "node build/index.js"
```

This will start both Webpack watch mode and your server, parallelly.

If you want to ensure a complete build before running your dev server, you can add `webpack &&` to the beginning of the above script.

Maybe a better way would be to integrate the Webpack watch mode into your dev server, then you would have to start only your dev server.